# Break out of Google Chromeframe on submitting a form to a new window?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, google-chrome-frame

I use Google Chromeframe for a web app.

Once in awhile I submit a form that opens up a new window (target=_blank) and streams a PDF to the browser.

Is it possible to prevent GCF from handling the PDF, and instead allow IE8's adobe plugin to do the work?

Thanks (in advance) for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just disable the chrome PDF reader.

navigate to gcf:about:plugins in IE and click disable on Chrome PDF Viewer